# Instead of calling actual REST endpoints when testing with Protractor -- can I replace the results with a json file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my angular application, I was able to use $httpbackend in my unit tests to mock up the data coming back but I want to be able to do the same in my end to end tests with protractor. I can't find any good resources on how to do this?

For example, in my unit test I was able to do this (GLOBAL.data is just a js file that contains JSON).

```
 $httpBackend.expect('GET','http://myserver/somerestendpoint')
            .respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
                console.log("Getting test response...");
                return [200,{'data' : GLOBAL.data}, {/*headers*/}];
            });
```

Now is it possible to do something similar for my end to end tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats the purpose of ngMocks
and more spcifically
$httpBackend

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: So based on this, should I *not* be trying to mock the $resource service (where the rest calls are taking place) with $httpBackend in my end to end tests?

Comment: thats correct, you can configure your $httpbackend to reply with whatever answer you want. http://prashantsahni.in/blog/2014/09/28/mocking-apis-integration-testing-with-protractor.html